# Punctuation assistance with complicated list of titles during a formal greeting

Tags: style, punctuation

I'm working on a scene in a high-fantasy setting where the main characters greet each other for the first time. Part of the greeting is also a definition of what each of the characters mean to each other. In this case, a flourish of titles establishes expectations:

> Wordlessly, he presented his beautiful, shimmering wife to Mary; who said, “And you, my Sarah: soother of the seas, queen of the oceans, sweet nurturer, and mother of music; I greet you.”

The simplified sentence is trying to say:

> He presented his wife to Mary who said, "Hello."

[Initial question]

What is the proper punctuation for **Mary who said** and for the "Sarah: [list of titles]"?

EDIT:

Semicolons are not necessary for separating the speaker from what she said. There is also no need for a semicolon before the list of titles. Rules would also state that there is no need for a semicolon to separate the long, introductory subordinate clause from the actual subject/verb within the quotes.

I think the answer is:

> Wordlessly, he presented his beautiful, shimmering wife to Mary, who said, “And you, my Sarah, soother of the seas, queen of the oceans, sweet nurturer, and mother of music, I greet you.”

Still unclear on the use of the comma after *Mary, who said* since the quote has to clearly belong to Mary and not the wife.

Comment: Hi, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: Read and read a lot.   Read high quality work.  And reread them over and over.

Comment: Yes, you need the comma after "who said" since it introduces a direct quote. Like this: _She said, "Hello."_ (I find the two adjectives "beautiful, shimmering" pretty awkward and would edit them out in an upcoming draft.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "*Mary; who*" in one place and "*Mary? who*" in another.

Both are wrong.  Use a comma.

Answer (score 1):

It's a disaster. When you began a sentence with the word 'wordlessly' you identified yourself as an ESOL novice.

[Bob] presented his beautiful, shimmering wife to Mary.

Mary bowed graciously and outstretched her hands to the esteemed guest. “And you, my Sarah: soother of the seas, queen of the oceans, sweet nurturer, and mother of music . . . How's it hangin'?"

Comment: I appreciate the commentary on style, I certainly do.  I know you can say: The frog said "owch!" after bob stepped on his head.  Or:  Bob heard a tiny "Owch!" after his metatarsals crushed the tiny amphibian.  However, the question related the punctuation of a sentence like:  Bob stepped on the frog who said "Owch!" Do you need a comma or not between frog and who?  is it clear the frog was speaking and not Bob?

Comment: You know best. The comma is optional, the 'who' is superfluous. "The little dog laughed to see such fun and the dish ran away with the spoon."

See: _Show don't tell._